# Tk canvas options keys list empy

Tags: python, tkinter, tk-toolkit

I find it really strange that the keys() method on the Tkinter.Canvas class returns a list of empty strings. Am I missing something, for other widgets those fields are populated with the correct options.

[image]

Comment: That looks like a bug.

Comment: @BryanOakley ... wonderful

Comment: Why does it matter? What are you trying to accomplish? There are other ways to programmatically get all of the configuration options.

Comment: @BryanOakley I don't need the configured options. I need the options available to configure for canvas. I'm building an xml based styling abstraction on top of tkinter so I need to check if the option tags in the xml file for the widget are valid.

Comment: @BryanOakley I agree that the Canvas-specific failure is a bug.  I tracked down the causes and opened a tracker issue with a proposed remedy (trivial).  https://bugs.python.org/issue26177

Comment: Please cut and paste interactive input/output into your question and format as 'code'.  The micro text in the image is hard to read and cannot be copied to the clipboard.  (Retyping is not much of an issue here, but usually is.)

Comment: @BryanOakley When you see something like this that is so obviously a bug, feel free to report it on the tracker (but then say so here ;-).  I look at less than half the tkinter questions and could have easily missed this.

Comment: @TerryJanReedy Would have done that, too bad command prompt is stuck in 1990 so I have no idea how it is even possible to copy it. I blame my company for making us use windows.

Comment: In Win10, ^C, ^V work as expected, and as standard on all other Windows programs.  Previously, one has to click upper left icon, select edit and then operation.  Really a pain.  Selecting instead 'properties' allow a change to make it slightly easier, as well as expanding buffer beyond 300 lines (which is not enough for the output from, for instance, `python -m test`).  There are other properties to customize, too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That appears to be a bug. However, you can get a list of all of the available options with the [configure](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/widget.htm#Tkinter.Widget.config-method) command:

```
c = tk.Canvas(...)
print(c.configure().keys())
```

Comment: In 3.x, this gives a view object, not a list.  `sorted[c.configure().keys()] gives a sorted list like with other-widget.keys()